# Unable to add reference to Native Dll in Windows Phone

Tags: .net, visual-c++, windows-phone-8

I tried to compile a C++ code in Windows Phone 8 as "Windows Runtime Component". But when i tried to add the output dll into my main windows phone 8 project, i get an error message box as "A reference to higher version or incompatible library cannot be added to the project". When i see the properties of dll in Windows Explorer, i See its version as 255.255.255.255, which i also the same as in my dll project and i cannot change it.

Can somebody tell how do i use this dll in my WinPhone8 project?

Thanx
Uday Gupta

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134407/unable-to-add-dll-reference-in-windows-phone-8