# Unable to add DLL reference in Windows Phone 8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, monogame

I am attempting to port a game to Windows Phone 8 with Visual studio 2012 and monogame. The problem is that I cant seem to add the DLL required, the error is "A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project"

The DLL that I am attempting to add is called Bass.net.dll and it was previously used in a normal .Net application.

Is there any way of adding this reference to the game so I can use it? I have read many articles online but all seem to have different explanations.

These include:[Not able to add class library dll to Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377890/not-able-to-add-class-library-dll-to-windows-phone-8)

and

http://pcmusings.wordpress.com/2012/10/31/vs2012-windows-phone-and-the-reference-to-a-higher-version-error/

which states that the DLL file should be unblocked, in my case the DLL and any related files are already unblocked so the sugestion doesn't apply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the dll need to be a Windows Phone dll or a Portable class library dll. You can't add a regular .net dll to a windows phone project.

Comment: Is there a way of converting the regular dll?

Comment: You need to create a new windows phone class library project and put the code in there. You can't directly convert because maybe some .net apis used in your .net library are not supported in windows phone.

Answer (score 8):

WP8 uses a subset of WinRT API, it don't support all Framework API

Just make a right-click on each of the DLL that you want to add, choose Properties and then click on the Unblock button

Comment: Where is this "Unblock" of which you speak?  If you mean [unblock because unsafe](http://www.telerik.com/analytics/resources/forums/monitor-integration/solution-to-a-reference-to-a-higher-version-or-incompatible-assembly-cannot-be-added-to-the-project-on-windows-8), this OP has, I believe, the issue Josue Yeray mentions instead.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the xml in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile78\SupportedFrameworks folder (changing the drive letter accordingly) and select [plattform].xml

and paste in your profile.

To know your profile open csproj with (notepad or sublime)